# How to format float number (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

i would like to know how to format float number.

```
Float          Want to display
1.0            1                   
1.52           1.5
1.58           1.6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would the format string `@"%.1g"` do it?