# String formatting: less decimals in %f float?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Well, I am using `%f` for displaying float values in my string. However, the values are too accurate (around 6 decimal digits after the point). I'd like to only display 1 decimal. But how?

Comment: Was there even an *attempt* to find some documentation first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set the float value to two decimal number in objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/how-to-set-the-float-value-to-two-decimal-number-in-objective-c) or [How to format float number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134260/how-to-format-float-number-objective-c) @pst

Comment: @pst: No, there wasn't any attempt as far as I can recall. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%0.2f` or some other number after the decimal point.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSLog(@"%0.1f", floatThing);
```

I think that should work. For more decimals change 0.1 to 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.DECIMAL_PRECISION_NUMBER_HEREf", someFloat]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

and

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html